# Shell script for word in $sentece How to change the value of word?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I need some help from this awesome community.

I'm trying to write a script that loops through each word of a sentence stored in a variable (for example SENTENCE).

Example:

```
for WORD in $SENTENCE
do

echo do something

done
```

The problem that I'm facing is that I need to change the value of WORD to restart the loop if a certain condition is true inside the loop.

Example:

```
for WORD in $SENTENCE
do

echo do something
if [[ $SOMETHING_HAPPENED == TRUE ]]; then
WORD=$FIRST_WORD_IN_SENTENCE
fi

done
```

Basically, I need to restart the loop if certain conditions are met (SOMETHING_HAPPENED), but I don't know how to do this properly.
If this was a normal C loop I would do it like this:

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
do_something();
if (SOMETHING_HAPPENED == TRUE){
i=0;
}
}
```

How do I do this in shell script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loop around your `for` loop that executes the `for` loop until the something doesn't happen:

```
repeat=yes
while [ "$repeat" = yes ]; do
    repeat=no
    for WORD in $SENTENCE; do
        # do something

        if [[ $SOMETHING_HAPPENED == TRUE ]]; then
            repeat=yes
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while [[ 1 ]]; do # infinite loop
  for word in $sentence; do
    …
    if [[ $condition ]]; then
      continue 2 # go to the next iteration of the *outer* loop
    fi
  done
  break # escape the outer loop
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 

By *outer* loop do you mean the while [[ 1 ]]; loop or the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

To restart the loop you can use BASH arrays and run your loop like this:

```
arr=( $sentence ) 

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do
    word="${arr[$i]}"

    # evaluate condition
    if [[ "$SOMETHING_HAPPENED" == TRUE ]]; then
         i=0
         continue
    fi

    echo "$word"
done
```